# Java Hibernate confused about table updates same ID statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

We have from some time this routine.. We are using `Hibernate and MySQL`.

```
Student->School the student table has a relationship with school. But in DB is not mandatory
the FK could be null..
```

We did like this I know is not the best approach but.

```
currentSession.save(student);
currentSession.save(student.getSchool());
currentSession.flush();
transaction.commit();
```

I have checked the SQL generates by Hibernate.. and i see.

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    student
    (C24, C01, C02, C03, C04, c07, c08, c09, c10, c11, C12, C13, C14, C15, c16, C17, C18, c19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C25, C26, C27, C28, C29, C30, C31, C32, C33, C34, C35,school_id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)


 Hibernate: 
 select
    last_insert_id()
 Hibernate: 
 insert 
 into
    school
    (C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: 
select
    last_insert_id()
```

This is OK with me is Student table the School column is `NULL` later I see..

```
Hibernate: 
update
    student
set
    school_id=? 
where
    ID=?
```

This i OK a extra sentence by using NULL but is still OK with me.. Here I am updating the relationship.

But the next sentence I don't get it.. why Hibernate would do such thing.. Update the same ID it's have previously being insert? We are using `auto-increment` approach in both tables.

```
Hibernate: 
update
    school
set
    id=? 
where
    ID=?
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: i'm not sure whats being asked here, try to improve your english in the question. no entiendo!!!

Comment: you should provide your `School` and `Student` complete table structures.